# When the Touchscreen Keyboard is Active Cannot Click on the UI Button

Tags: unity-game-engine, keyboard, textmeshpro

I am making a game with the chat mechanic's and everything is working smoothly, but there is one issue.

When I clicked on the input field and the touchscreen keyboard opened, I write the message and when I try to send the message by clicking on the Send button which is above the touchscreen keyboard, I cannot click on the button. Instead it closed the keyboard and then I have to click on the Send button again which is very frustrating and UX point of view.

I want to know if there is any way when I click on the Send button it works at the same time the keyboard closes. The issue appears on Android; not tried on IOS until now.